# Closure Compiler: purpose of --language_in and --language_out options?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

[Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) has these CLI options:

- `--language_in` – Sets what language spec that input sources conform.
- `--language_out` – Sets what language spec the output should conform to.

---

## Language in

What is the meaning of `--language_in`? I assume it's one of the following:

1. A declaration/promise that the source code does conform to the specified language. The compiler won't verify that it does; it simply trusts that it does.
2. An instruction to the compiler to verify that the source code conforms to the specified language. The compiler will raise an error if it doesn't.

[This documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations) seems to imply meaning #1:

> Projects can specify which Ecmascript language version they **intend** by using the `--language_in` flag.

However, [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref#language) indicates meaning #2 (I'm assuming that the `language` webservice option is connected to the `--language_in` CLI option):

> The `language` parameter refers to which version of ECMAScript to assume when checking for errors in your code.
>
> `ECMASCRIPT3` – Checks code assuming ECMAScript 3 compliance, and **gives errors for code using features only present in ECMAScript 5.**

If I compile this code using the [webservice](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/):

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @language ECMASCRIPT3
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var x = Object.freeze({
    y: 3,
    z: 4
});

console.log(x);
```

it doesn't give an error that [`Object.freeze()` doesn't exist in ECMAScript 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Specifications). Why not?

---

## Language out

Similarly, what is the meaning of `--language_out`? I assume it means:

- An instruction to the compiler that it must produce output which conforms to the specified language.

But if I compile this code:

```
var x = Object.freeze({
    y: 3,
    z: 4
});

console.log(x);
```

with this CLI command, specifying `--language_out ECMASCRIPT3`:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js test.js \
    --js_output_file test.min.js \
    --language_out ECMASCRIPT3 \
    --compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
    --warning_level VERBOSE \
    --summary_detail_level 3
```

no errors or warnings are raised:

```
0 error(s), 0 warning(s), 100.0% typed
```

and the compiled code is:

```
var a=Object.freeze({y:3,z:4});console.log(a);
```

So the output doesn't conform to `ECMASCRIPT3` (because it contains `Object.freeze()`). Why not?

Comment: Try with something like `var foo = {delete: 42};`. In ES3, reserved keywords are not allowed to be used like this in object literals.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `Object.freeze()` is not a *syntactic* error. The compiler has no way of knowing whether your code at some point extends the Object prototype. Thus `Object.freeze()` is perfectly valid ECMAScript 3 code.

Similarly,

```
var x = {};
x.something();
```

is perfectly valid code. It will throw an exception at runtime, but it's not a syntax error.

An ES5 feature that should illustrate those options is the use of reserved words as property names in object literals:

```
var x = { if: "hello world" };
```

Another would be getter/setter initializers:

```
var x = { get hello() { return "world"; } };
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I agree that the call to `Object.freeze()` is not a syntactic error. But with `--language_in ECMASCRIPT3`, if you change the call to something like `Object.foobar()`, then the compiler raises a warning: `JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property foobar never defined on Object`. And if you call `Object.freeze()` without any arguments, then the compiler raises a warning: `JSC_WRONG_ARGUMENT_COUNT: Function Object.freeze: called with 0 argument(s). Function requires at least 1 argument(s) and no more than 1 argument(s).` So the compiler knows the function expects 1 argument.

Comment: I think the problem is that the compiler should not be using its [ECMAScript 5 extern](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/es5.js) when `--language_in ECMASCRIPT3` is specified. Although `Object.freeze()` is not a syntactic error, it should raise a warning: `JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property freeze never defined on Object`.

Comment: @TachyonVortex if it gives errors in those cases, then I agree that it should disallow `Object.freeze()` for ES3 code. Maybe it assumes you'll be using a shim or something, but I would consider that a bug if I were a Closure user.

Comment: Currently, we use the same set of externs regardless of the language_in flag. Ideally we'd have a simple flag where you can specify what kind of environment your code is going to run in (either "the web" including older browsers, or "the modern web", or node.js, etc.) and you'd get the right language mode, and the right set of externs. For now, you can specify those manually with `--language_in` and `--externs` flags. As Pointy says, `--language_in` controls language features and syntax while `--externs` indicates what APIs are available. Filed github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/966

Comment: @MatrixFrog It'd certainly be nice to have an `--env` option with presets for common environments. But the [list of externs](https://goo.gl/BpIm3R) actually consists of two separate categories: [ECMAScript (standard built-in objects)](https://goo.gl/jvqc2d), and [APIs](https://goo.gl/RmqzO7) (defined by W3C, WHATWG, etc). Like Pointy, I consider it a bug that the [ES5 extern](https://goo.gl/TPKTiD) is loaded when `--language_in ECMASCRIPT3` is specified. As you said, `--language_in` controls language features, and the ES5 extern defines language features (not an API).